# Linq DbContext - filter on if other list contains a value

Tags: linq, entity-framework, dbcontext

I need a Linq query to include an item in the result only if a value exists in another list. I've been looking at here and in MSDN doc and just can't get the syntax right.

I have a list of user roles:

```
var userRoles = _identityManager.GetUserRoles(userId);
var roles = userRoles.Select(role => role.RoleId).ToList();
```

And I want the query against DbContext to include an item only if its AccessRole is in the roles list:

```
documents = context.ClientDocuments
.Where(d => d.ClientID == clientId)
//&& roles.contains d.AccessRole // pseudo code
.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateCreated)
.Select(
    doc => new ClientDocumentDto()
    {
        DocumentID = doc.ClientDocumentID,
        Name = doc.Name,
        Project = doc.Project,
        DocumentType = doc.DocumentType,
        DateCreated = doc.DateCreated,
        AccessRole = doc.AccessRole
    });
```

Comment: d.AccessRole is a roleId?

Comment: Yes Alexander, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about specifying the condition in the `Where` clause?

```
documents = context.ClientDocuments
.Where(d => d.ClientID == clientId && roles.Contains(d.AccessRole))

.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateCreated)
.Select(
    doc => new ClientDocumentDto()
    {
        DocumentID = doc.ClientDocumentID,
        Name = doc.Name,
        Project = doc.Project,
        DocumentType = doc.DocumentType,
        DateCreated = doc.DateCreated,
        AccessRole = doc.AccessRole
    });
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do Omri (see the pseudo code). Just can't get the syntax right.

Comment: @GDB Doesn't that syntax work though? (notice the extra `roles.Contains(d.AccessRole)`)

Comment: My apologies Omri. Your suggested syntax is exactly right. My brain got in the way of my typing the update. Thanks very much!